# PHP Mysql Query with Time Interval

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php that extracts information from a mysql database just fine, however when I tried to add the functionality to check for data depending on an interval I am not getting any data from the database, just replies with an empty result.  When I run it in Phpmyadmin it works just fine.  Here's the code:

```
$result = mysql_query("
    SELECT * FROM SensorLog
    WHERE (SensorTag='$requestedSensor' and TimeEntered<'$end'
        and TimeEntered>'$start');
") or die(mysql_error());
```

start and end are of the form: 2014-01-22 15:36:37 just like my timestamped column in the database.

What am I doing wrong here? I assume something is wrong with the query but I can't figure out what.

Comment: Fields are stored as dates or varchar?

Comment: `mysql_query` is an obsolete interface and should not be used in new applications and will be removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). If you're new to PHP, a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help.

Comment: I'm not sure the `;` at the end should be there.

Comment: The () are superfluous remove them,AND priority is enough.

Comment: I removed the ; and it still doesn't work.

Comment: also tried rearranging the code to the following:    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM SensorLog WHERE (SensorTag='$requestedSensor' and TimeEntered>='$start' and TimeEntered<='$end')") or die(mysql_error());  Also dates are of type "timestamp" in mysql

Comment: Put the query into a variable first, e.g. `$sql = "SELECT ..."` and then `echo $sql;` it out. Make sure what you're building in PHP **EXACTLY** matches what you ran in phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same can be achieved using BETWEEN clause as follows:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM SensorLog 
WHERE (SensorTag='$requestedSensor' and TimeEntered BETWEEN '$end' AND '$start')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

If date start and date end have the same value, the query should be `TimeEntered >= $start and TimeEntered <= $end`

Comment: they don't have the same value, that wouldn't accomplish too much.